# How to Overcome Partitions On Flash that can not be removed, as a result of using the software "Startup disk Creator"?

Tags: 16.04, startup-disk-creator

At first I wanted to make me into a bootable Linux flash LTS 16.04, After the installation process is finished I want to restore my flash as before. when I checked, it turned my flash partitioned for making bootable "startup disk creator".

[image: Disk management]

when I want to delete the partition had made an error.

> Error Formatting Volume: This partition cannot be modified because it contains a partition table; please reinitialize layout of the whole
>   device. (udisks-error-quark, 11)

and when I want to delete partitions also occurred error:

```
Eror Deleting Volume: Error deleting partition /dev/sdb1:
Command-line `parted --script "/dev/sdb" "rm 1"' exited with non-zero exit status 1:
Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes. (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried using gparted? I've been successful with it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open terminal and issue the following:

```
fdisk -l
```

Here you will be able to see your flash drive number. Let's assume it is `sdX`

Now again issue the following in terminal:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero  of=/dev/sdX
```

It will take some time to execute this command

Now issue the following:

```
sudo gparted
```

A window will open

From top right drop down menu select `sdX`

Click on device tab --> Create partition table --> gpt --> Apply

Right click on the grey bar below and select New partition --> fat32 --> OK --> Apply.

Close gparted and unmount the flash drive before pulling it out

That's it

Comment: I suspect that `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=1M count=1` would work equally well, and go a lot faster.

Comment: This is the only solution worked for me. Thanks!!!!

Comment: gparted cannot see my usb stick after "sudo dd if=/dev/zero  of=/dev/sdX". I get "end of file while reading /dev/sdb" error and "The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes"

Comment: Thanks but it is really really slow didnt tried Rob's whey..maybe it is faster.. next time..

Comment: You do not need to zero the whole partition. You'll waste your time. I personally use:
`sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=2048 count=32`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to reformat the entire USB device, here are steps. Source: [a relevant user interface bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=768031).

- Open the Disks application.
- Select the USB device.
- Use the hamburger menu in the top right of Disks and select "Format disk". This will allow you to format the entire disk, not just a partition of it.

Comment: After that, we need to create a partition too, as the above steps will create free space.